# web2py readonly fields in appadmin

Tags: python, forms, web2py

Excerpt from web2py documentation:

```
Forms created with
form = SQLFORM(...,ignore_rw=True)
ignore the readable and writable attributes and always show all fields. Forms in appadmin ignore them by default.
```

How can I make them behave as normal fields and not ignore those parameters? Should this be done with custom css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `ignore_rw` top-level variable in the appadmin.py controller. You could set that to `False`.